# How to add javascript code into Divi child theme?

Tags: functions, javascript, child-theme

I want to add this JavaScript code into my Divi child theme. I have made a directory for the js file inside the Divi child theme folder. The name of the js file is `"selectpage.js"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".select_page").text("your-text-here");
});
</script>
```

I added this code into my `functions.php` file. This is not working, I think I am doing something wrong with the `wp_enqueue_script` directory. Because when I go to inspect on the site it tries to locate the js files in the `/wp-incldudes/js/scripts`. Does it matter where I put the js file inside my child theme folder? It is only for changing the text in the mobile center-menu "select_page".

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'divi-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );


**wp_enqueue_script( 'et_mobile_nav_menu', $template_dir . '/js/selectpage.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );**



?>
```

Thanks in Advance, Davíð

Comment: Scripts should be enqueued using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook - [example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#comment-276) - and take time to thoroughly read the `wp_enqueue_script()` [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). For Divi-specific stuff (like Divi script handle), consult the Divi support forums/site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, change code in functions.php to:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'divi-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'et_mobile_nav_menu', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/selectpage.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Now your script should be located at: `/wp-content/themes/divi-child/js/selectpage.js`

Comment: I tried this and it still does not work, this is the site I am doing it for http://ro-fridur.is/, I see one error when I go to inspect but I dont know what it means. Maybe it is not searching for the script in the right location ?

Comment: Yes it is correct i have a divi-child directory and the js file is inside /wp-content/themes/divi-child/js/selectpage.js. What should I change from Divi to divi-child ?

Comment: @davidhlyns I updated the code in my answer, paste it in and now it should work.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @davidhlyns no problem. Please upvote and accept the answer.